# video controls for videojs appearing as text instead of icons

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework, video.js

I am now faced with the situation such that I have the videos playing properly, but the controls are only text instead of the normal icons that should appear. I am wondering what is the mistake I have made. If not, can someone tell me if there is anything wrong.

Here are snippets from my codebase:

the scripts imported in my `index.html` file:

```
<script src="lib/video.copy.js/dist/video.min.js"></script>
<script>
  videojs.options.flash.swf = "lib/video.copy.js/dist/video-js.swf"
</script>
<link href="lib/video.copy.js/dist/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

the code snippet which is used to play the videos using video.js:

```
$scope.specialtiesVideo = function (id) 
        {
            var element = id;
            console.log(id);
            console.log($scope.videos[id].$$unwrapTrustedValue())
            var srcfile = $scope.videos[id].$$unwrapTrustedValue();
            var webmfile = srcfile.substr(0, srcfile.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".webm";
            var mp4file = srcfile.substr(0, srcfile.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".mp4";
            var confirm = document.getElementById(id);
            console.log(document.getElementById(id));
            $scope.videoplayers[id] = videojs(id);
            console.log(document.getElementById(id));
            console.log("videojs enabled for the video identified by ID :"+id);
            if(isYT($scope.videos[id].$$unwrapTrustedValue()))
            {
                console.log("Youtube type videos");
                $scope.videoplayers[id].src(
                    [
                        {
                            type: "video/youtube",
                            src: $scope.videos[id].$$unwrapTrustedValue()
                        }
                    ]
                );
            }
            else
            {
                $scope.videoplayers[id].src(
                    [
                        {
                            type: "video/mp4",
                            src: mp4file
                        },
                        {
                            type: "video/webm",
                            src: webmfile
                        }
                    ]
                );
            }
            $scope.videoplayers[id].aspectRatio("16:9");
            $scope.videoplayers[id].autoplay(false);
            $scope.videoplayers[id].controls(true);
        };
```

but this is the result I am getting:

[image: the result of my code execution]

I am wondering if my code is calling the videojs files correctly as I don't see any css rules from the videojs css file.

I am also showing the file structure of video.js, just in case:

[image]

I also think that the following code snippet has something to do with this (correct me if I am wrong) :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: VideoJS;
  src: url("font/VideoJS.eot?#iefix") format("eot"), 
       url("font/VideoJS.woff") format("woff"),
       url("font/VideoJS.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("font/VideoJS.svg#svgFontName") format('svg');
    }
```

please let me know how this can be solved, thanks in advance

**Correction :Video-js.css file is being used but the font-face code snippet mentioned above still does not work. Any solution that can help play videos in the expected format is welcome**

**Also, I created some css to customize the videojs elements as the style rules from the video-js.css file did not seem to have any effect**

Custom css code:

```
.vjs-tech {
    /*height: 100%;*/
    height: 50px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.comment-container {
    z-index: 2 !important;
}

.docdetails {
    z-index: 3 !important;
}

.vjs-fluid {
    padding-top: 0% !important;
}
```

**UPDATE: Hey guys, I got the solution. It's simple really, i had forgotten put the required classes as the video tag property without which the video-js.css file would not be called**

here is the snippet that solved the problem:

```
class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"
```

Comment: did you go to the console and made sure the font files are loading ?

Comment: @PrashantGhimire: I don't think they were loading

Comment: There it is, make sure its loaded and try again!

Comment: I feel that those font files are the solution to my problem

Comment: I said it should work if the font files are loaded in the CSS.

Comment: Try running in Browser. Console would catch if reference to any file is wrong.

Comment: @hva.narola : that's exactly what I have done, run in the browser, and I assure you, there are no errors related to this

Comment: If it looks like the screenshot, the entire video.js CSS is not loaded, not just the font. (You'd have the player skin with junk icons if it were just the font).

Comment: @misterben: I see, is there a solution to load the entire video-js css file? cdn is one method i can come up with but i seem to have problems with it currently. or is it an error on my part because of which, the file is not being loaded?